# Read heroku environment variables from gradle build script

Tags: heroku, gradle, environment

My build script has to have a section:

```
flyway {
    url = System.getenv('JDBC_DATABASE_URL')
    user = System.getenv('JDBC_DATABASE_USERNAME')
    password = System.getenv('JDBC_DATABASE_PASSWORD')
}
```

The problem is while those environment variables are visible when I run

```
heroku run printenv --remote staging | grep JDBC
```

They are null within gradle build script where *stage* task is defined.

What is the reason for this? How to come around this?

Answer (score 0):

Those variables do not seem to be available during deployment, but you can get the data from the environment variable DATABASE_URL instead.

An example is shown by robert_difalco in https://stackoverflow.com/a/27988242:

> ```
>     URI dbUri = new URI(System.getenv("DATABASE_URL"));
>
>     String username = dbUri.getUserInfo().split(":")[0];
>     String password = dbUri.getUserInfo().split(":")[1];
>     int port = dbUri.getPort();
>
>     String dbUrl = "jdbc:postgresql://" + dbUri.getHost() + ":" + port + dbUri.getPath();
> ```

Comment: Please insert a relevant example to your answer directly. Links can get broken, so it's a general recommendation at SO.